# Usage of imperfective раздобывать

Tags: глаголы, вид

I've only ever heard this verb in its perfective form **раздобыть**, yet the dictionary lists **раздобывать** as its imperfective. However is it ever used? The only context I could possibly imagine is something like: Здесь долго раздобывают такие вещи на черном рынке. Is that possible?

Comment: http://goo.gl/PGl9dT

Comment: "[На то,] чтобы раздобыть это на чёрном рынке, уйдёт вечность" would be fine. This word is rather archaic and changing its form sounds strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Раздобыть* means to get something rare *by chance*, as opposed to *добыть/добывать* - *by making proper efforts*.

> Вы не поверите, сегодня я раздобыл для своей коллекции [картину]
>   Айвазовского.

*Раздобыть* even carries a hidden meaning '**for once**' (by strange coincidence, it reminds the expression "как-то *раз добыл*"). It could explain why the imperfective form *раздобывать* (meaning some person gets lucky with something all the time) is almost never used and even if used properly (about smth. happening not too often and each time *for once*) might sound strange (as in your example). Here's my attempt:

> Порой ему везло, и он раздобывал для музея что-нибудь удивительное и
>   неожиданное.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. So the meaning of раздобыть is essentially: to finally manage to get one's hands on something, if I'm not mistaken. Now I understand perfect the aspectual dynamics at play here. Thanks again :)

Comment: I would translate you example as: Sometimes he would hit the jackpot and score something remarkable and rare for the museum. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, your translation is correct.

Comment: Alexander you have a great way of explaining things and your English is excellent. I look forward to your future answers to my questions! :)

Answer (score 2):

> However is it ever used?

Though this verb is a "legal" one, I can't think of any good reason to use it.

> Здесь долго раздобывают такие вещи на черном рынке. Is that possible?

Not sure why you say "долго" - it seems to have no sense in this context. I'd rather say: "Здесь можно раздобыть такие вещи только на черном рынке" or something like that. So instead of "раздобывать", I believe, one may always say either "добывать" or "можно раздобыть" etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I was trying to render in Russian (obviously not very successfully:) is that "It takes a long time to get a hold of those things on the black market."

Comment: @CocoPop it’s possible, though is not very “euphonic”: «дворовый пёс прожил всю жизнь, раздобывая пищу». “It takes a long time to get a hold of those things on the black market” could be translated as «Такие вещи [долго] раздобываются [даже] на черном рынке». «Даже» stays to make an expression even stronger here.

Comment: @mudasobwa `«дворовый пёс прожил всю жизнь, раздобывая пищу»` Again, though it's possible but sounds much worse than just "добывая".

Comment: In my opinion, there is a minor connotation added in «раздобывая»: «добывая пищу» roughly means “working for a food,” while «раздобывая» is closer to “searching for a food.” Plus it’s possible to «добывать пищу» in one single place, while «раздобывать» is more about running around and searching for it.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you both for your insights.

Comment: @CocoPop: *такие вещи на чёрном рынке не сразу раздобудешь*

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is gramatically correct, but the word "раздобывать" is of informal style, consider using other words if not speaking informally.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitriy, for your insights. I'm not so much concerned with formality as I am with grammar and syntax. In my opinion, when studying the usage of a language, the informal register is as valid as the formal, if not more, for it reflects the way people express themselves when they're themselves and not putting on airs.